# Launch process from CGI in Linux

Tags: linux, process, cgi

I need to launch server executables from terminal. They are running through wine (because those executables are for Windows) in the background. If I launch them normally, from Terminal, those work without any problem.

Now I'm trying to make CGI (bash) script and launch servers from website, but script doesn't launch processes. I thought that it has something to do with wine, but no, script doesn't launch any processes at all.

I'm building that system on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, after that scripts would go onto Debian server.

So, the question is: is it even possible to run background process from CGI scripts? If yes, would you please explain how?

Comment: What kind of processes do you want to run from your CGI??? I really don't think that running Windows programs thru wine from a CGI is a good idea. Try to find the native Linux equivalents of these Windows programs.

Comment: I wan't to run LFS game servers and InSim applications which are made on C# platform. So, that would be a no-no.

Comment: For C# on Linux, http://mono-project.com/ is probably the best way.

Comment: I'd really prefer using same old Visual Studio on in VirtualBox. I have already tried Mono, we'd have to change quite a huge amount of our source code just to make it run without errors.

Answer (score 0):

A [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) program is like any other program, except that it is supposed to run quickly and to follow the CGI protcol (in particular, regarding to stdout output).

As with any other Linux program, you can (subject to limitations and permissions on your system) run processes, using [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) like e.g. [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) and many others.

I suggest to read a good Unix programming book like [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) abd [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). We can't teach all that here in a few minutes.

You could also run processes using the library [system(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) and [popen(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) functions (of course these functions are implemented using syscalls, inside GNU `libc`)

Don't forget the stateless property of CGIs; you may consider using [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) or SCGI instead.

(A program started thru `wine` from a CGI might fail, e.g. because it has no [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11)
server to talk to; For C# programs, consider [Mono](http://mono-project.com/) on Linux).

<sup>Another possibility could be to run Windows in some VM, and have your CGI interact with such virtualized Windows programs. Not knowing Windows, I have no idea about the issues of such an approach.</sup>